# Change column name by string ID in old column name

Tags: r, dataframe, col

Consider I have a data frame in R with the col names:

```
data:
 A  B  C  D  E  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 Vx...
 2  3  4  5  6  5  5  5  5  2  2
```

how could I grab all values that contain a `V` and replace it with `Sample`
so I get:

data:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4 Sample5 Sample6 Samplex...
   2  3  4  5  6     5       5      5        5       2       2
```

I would need a universal solution as in my data frames the amount of columns with V as well as the position is changing. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution is to use `sub` with *regex* to modify the column names, here `^V` matches letter `V` at the beginning of the string, which gets replaced with `Sample`:

```
names(df) <- sub("^V", "Sample", names(df))
df
#  A B C D E Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4 Sample5 Sample6
#1 2 3 4 5 6       5       5       5       5       2       2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to subset the 'V' column names and update on the dataset

```
i1 <- grep("^V", names(df))
names(df)[i1] <- paste0("Sample", seq_along(i1))
df
#  A B C D E Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4 Sample5 Sample6
#1 2 3 4 5 6       5       5       5       5       2       2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(A = 2L, B = 3L, C = 4L, D = 5L, E = 6L, V1 = 5L, 
V2 = 5L, V3 = 5L, V4 = 5L, V5 = 2L, V6 = 2L), .Names = c("A", 
 "B", "C", "D", "E", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```